# How to cancel a specific firestore realtime listener with a button in react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a realtime listener on a firestore collection to get the latest data. The function I'm using is like below,the function is attached to a button press.

```
function getItems(selectedCategory){

const subscriber =  firestore()
    .collection('CollectionName')
    .doc('documentName')
    .collection('CollectionName2')
    .where("category", "==", selectedCategory)    
    .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
        console.log('Total Docs: ', documentSnapshot.size)
         
            documentSnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
             console.log('doc ID: ', documentSnapshot.id); 
            });
    });
    unSubscriptions.push(subscriber); //to detach the listener when page is changed(usefocuseffect)
  
}
```

when I call the function I can get the results and render them accordingly. But if I invoke the function again with a different input variable for "selectedCategory" it also logs the results. The thing is if any changes happened with the first occurrence (the first input variable) it also gets logged. I believe this happens because the listener for the first input parameter is still being active. Is there a way I can detach the first listener before invoking a second one.

P.S : I'm using a return function with useFocusEffect to cleanup the listeners when the page goes out of focus(which works) but I want to do a similar thing with a button press.

Answer (score 1):

`onSnapshot()` returns a **function** that you need to call to detach your listener.

So you need to simply do `subscriber()` (note the parentheses) when clicking your button.

The specific doc is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).

Comment: I'm using RNFirebase. Does the nodejs documentations also applies to it?

Comment: Yes it’s the same for the Firestore Node.js Client: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/query